# Is my book to similar to Matched by Allie Condie

Tags: fiction, plagiarism, ideas

I'm currently writing a book about a government that designs its citizens' DNA and assigns them each to a job or purpose in life best suited to improve the society as a whole. My main character does not like the purpose she was made for. She then has to  go to training for said job, which is a Security Agent. She has to learn how to break away from her assigned purpose and find her own passion in life. I'm wondering if this is too similar to Matched by Allie Condie.

Comment: Is my story too similar isn't a question ultimately about writing. It's in one sense an ask for critique and in another for an opinion. It is too broad and non technical. This is probably not the best place to provide you an answer.

Comment: I've never heard of Matched, but IMO this reminds me of the first episode of *Futurama*.

Comment: Have you tried asking in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification   to see whether they would recognize Matched from the description of your own story?